# Amazon Quicksight predefined filter values

Tags: filter, amazon-quicksight

I have the following values used to filter data.
Is there a way to predefine set of values and be able to filter by Europe/US?

City
Amsterdam
New York
Paris
London
Miami
LA

Only way I think about doing it is to create predefined selection on different sheets